# Can't save iptables rule on Google Cloud VM instance (CentOS 7)

Tags: google-compute-engine, iptables, google-cloud-platform, centos7

I'm running Tomcat8 on CentOS7 in Google VM instance on port 8080.
I setup the iptables rule to map all external connections to port 80 to 8080

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

After that I save the rule with

```
service iptables save
```

Tomcat works fine and accessible from outside via port 80.
The rule is saved in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.

```
...
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
...
```

but after server reboot the rule is not applied.
It's still in the file `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` but not in action when I run

```
iptables-save
```

It seems that iptables rules are restored from somewhere else.

How can I persist the rule properly to preserve it after reboot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve the issue with IPtables you can do the following:

```
yum install iptables-services
systemctl mask firewalld
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl enable ip6tables
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl start iptables
systemctl start ip6tables
```

However, Centos7 is using [FirewallD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Migration_Planning_Guide-Security_and_Access_Control.html) now instead. In order to apply the firewall, you need to check first what are the available zones and which zones are active on FirewallD by running these commands:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

If public zone is active for example, you can run these commands to enable port forwarding (port 80 to 8080 in your case):

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent
```

Once done, you can reload the rules to make sure everything is OK by running this command:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

You can check `man firewall-cmd` for more information.

Comment: @4ilin if my answer was useful in resolving your issue, I would appreciate it if you can accept the answer so that it can help others if they encounter the same issue. Thanks